# How do I get the Terminal command files (.command files) ask for words?

Tags: terminal, command-line

I'm making a command, but there is no way to get the command files `(known as .command files)` to ask for words.
like confirmations such as:

```
Continue to make directory? y/n
```

And commands use to confirm and ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.command scripts run in Terminal windows (that is, when you double-click a .command file, it opens a Terminal window, and you can use that window to interact with the script). You can use that to prompt the user and get input; exactly how you do that depends on the scripting language you're using (which is determined by the shebang (starts with `#!`) line at the beginning of the script. In bash, you'd do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Continue to make directory? y/n " makedir
if [[ "$makedir" = [Yy] ]]; then
    mkdir somedirectory
fi
```

In zsh, the syntax for adding a prompt to the `read` command is different, and it has a `-q` option specifically for y/n questions (that succeeds if the answer is "y" or "Y", and can be used directly in an `if`):

```
#!/bin/zsh

if read -q "makedir?Continue to make directory? y/n "; then
    mkdir somedirectory
fi
```

In other languages, you'd do... whatever you do in that language to prompt for and accept input.